# failed join device to azure hybrid ad

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, scp

hi i'm trying to join one of our organization's device to the hybrid azure ad, since i got the error "you can't get there from here" every time that i try to authenticate with azure apps (teams, sharepoint, office 365 ect.).
in the device event viewer i'm getting the following error:

```
Automatic registration failed at join phase. 
Exit code: Unknown HResult Error code: 0x801c0021 
Server error:  
Tenant type: undefined 
Registration type: undefined 
Debug Output: 
joinMode: Join
drsInstance: undefined
registrationType: undefined
tenantType: undefined
tenantId: undefined
configLocation: undefined
errorPhase: discover
adalCorrelationId: ********************
adalLog:
undefined
adalResponseCode: 0x0
```

this is the device state
dsregcmd /status

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device State                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

             AzureAdJoined : NO
          EnterpriseJoined : NO
              DomainJoined : YES
                DomainName : *****
```

I understand from another working device that the proper configuration output should be yes on the azureAdJoined Parameter and device name parameter should appear.

after some research online i assume that it has something to do with the device being "domain joined" and not hybrid azure ad joind. is it true? if so, how can i change the joined level and the Azureadjoined value? if not, can anyone help me understand why is it happening and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

These event IDs occur when the infrastructure isn't prepared for Hybrid join. When the device tries to do Hybrid join, the registration fails, and the events are logged.

Since your AzureAdJoined status is "NO", you need to [troubleshoot further using the troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/troubleshoot-hybrid-join-windows-current). For Windows 10 1803 and above, look for the "Previous Registration" subsection in the "Diagnostic Data" section of the join status output. The "Error Phase" field denotes the phase of the join failure while "Client ErrorCode" denotes the error code of the Join operation. These will let you know why it is failing.